# Linked server with dot in name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT PID,surname,forenames,othername,date_of_birth FROM OPENQUERY(compact,'SELECT PID,surname,forenames,othername,date_of_birth FROM Order.PERSONS')
```

This is run from SQL Studio Manager.  Order.Persons is an Oracle database.  This query works as intended.  Is it possible to do this:

```
SELECT PID,surname,forenames,othername,date_of_birth FROM OPENQUERY(compact.world,'SELECT PID,surname,forenames,othername,date_of_birth FROM Order.PERSONS')
```

i.e. the change the linked server name to compact.world.

Comment: Try using `[compact.world]` instead.

Comment: ...or better yet, stop naming things with bad characters in them.

Comment: @user2989408, thanks.  That is it.  Please post an answer for credit.+1.

Comment: @w0051977 no Aaarons answer is correct. Don't use a . in the server name. There is no concievable benefit to doing it this way. None.

Comment: You don't always have total control over all the namespaces you touch.  It's safer to get in the habit of always delimiting your identifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `[compact.world]` instead of `compact.world`.